# Can mutool split a big PDF file into individual PDF pages?

Tags: pdf, conversion

I can't figure out if [mutool](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-convert.html) can split each page of a multi-page PDF into individual PDF files.

This works:

```
mutool draw -o p%d.png input.pdf
```

This doesn't (It only creates a single, bigger PDF with every other page black):

```
mutool draw -o %d.pdf input.pdf
```

This doesn't work either:

```
mutool draw -F pdf -o %d.pdf input.pdf
```

Maybe mutool just can't do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS version, and release, are you using? Which release of MuPDF is installed? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Mutool can definitely split a PDF into individual PDF pages, but I don't know if you can do this by running just one mutool command. You could of course solve the problem pretty easily with a for loop, though. You don't even need to go as far as writing a script, like I did here. It would suffice as a one-liner.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

help() {
  printf "%s\n" "Usage: split-pdf input [output]" \
                "Leave the extension off of output" > /dev/stderr
  exit 1
}

input="$1"
output="$2" # leave off extension

if [ ! "$input" ]; then
  help
fi

if [ ! "$output" ]; then
  output=$(basename "$input" .pdf)
fi


# Get the number of pages
pagecount=$(pdfinfo "$input" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}')

# Determine length of number for purposes of zero-padding
pad=$(printf "$pagecount" | wc -c)

for i in $(seq 1 $pagecount); do
  count=$(printf "%0${pad}d" $i)
  mutool merge -o "$output-$count.pdf" "$input" $i
done
```

I tested it on a 972-page PDF, and it took about 5 seconds on my Intel i5 Lenovo ThinkPad. If you need it to be faster, then perhaps you'll need to write some code and use the MuPDF library instead. (Or someone with better knowledge can provide a better answer.) You can read about the library at [MuPDF's website](https://mupdf.com/docs/library.html). It suggests you could use a Java library that provides classes similar to `mutool run` tool, which I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

The command that Mutool suggest for output pdf to pdf is ["mutool clean"](https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutool-clean.html)
in docs states.

> ...It can be used to repair broken files, expand compressed streams, **filter out a range of pages**, etc.

Designed for a whole file needs adaption to output single pages. Thus you will need to build a loop from number of pages, to precede the command. I suggest for Windows users this can be done in a single line. Remember in a batch file you will need %%i in 3 places. Other shell commands can do similar, as suggested by [kGdmioT](https://superuser.com/a/1728652/1769247) 's answer.

```
mutool info in.pdf|find "Pages:">pages.txt&set /p pages=<pages.txt&for /L %i in (1,1,%pages:~7%) do @mutool clean -cgggg in.pdf page-%i.pdf %i
```

Many constructs like forms should still work but some links or outline bookmarks (now pointless) may naturally need to be adjusted.

[image]